How to open four terminal section in iTerm like a grid?
I have a bash script that open four terminals showing the output of their executed commands in four windows/tabs to see their output together. I need to create a bash or AppleScript file that when is executed opens iTerm with four sections with a grid layout like the image below. How can I achieve that? (I'm not looking to open four windows that are aligned like a grid, but four section in one iTerm window)


If you used iTerm2, you can set up a window with your 4 splits, 2 horizontal with 2 vertical. Then you can Save the Window Arraignment (Under the Window menu) In the Preferences, under Arraignment, you can set this new setting as default. Command-Shift-R will restore your window arraignment as needed.

Or see here as well. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22445/how-can-i-save-tabs-in-iterm-2-so-they-restore-the-next-time-the-app-is-run#25084

Maybe using tmux or its modern alternative zellij
For tmux, after pressing your leader key (default: ctrl+b), press " to split horizontally or % to split vertically.

Under the Shell menu for iTerm2, there are options to split vertically and horizontally. Then under the Window menu you can save the arrangement.


And now I see that ErniePC12 gave this answer in a comment above.
